# Cannot import my widget inside my mainwindows using pyside2 and QtDesigner

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt-designer, pyside2

every one. I'm not the best in interface, and I have an issue here when I try to import one of my widget into a mainwindow I've created. Here is how I proceed:

First I create my own widget using QtDesigner:

[image: PICTURE]

I rename the objectName field with MyWidget then I save it into a MyWidget.ui file
I convert the ui file into a .py one with this command: pyside2-uic MyWidget.ui > MyWidget.py

For an unknown reason a line starting with (base) is inserted at the beginning of the fresh .py file. I remove this useless line.

Then I create a mainWindows with qtDesigner, and I locate in it 4 widget areas.

[image: PICTURE]

Then I right click on one widget and I click "Promote to". I change the class name into "MyWidget" and press "add". Then I press the promote button. I do the same thing for the 3 others widget areas and I save the ui before I convert it into a .py file (and I remove the first line with (base)...).

every files are located in the same folder.

Then if I try to run the MainWindow.py file using python I have the following error:

python MainWindow.py

```
from mywidget import MyWidget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mywidget'
```

following the two files code:

Fist, MyWidget.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MyWidget.ui',
# licensing of 'MyWidget.ui' applies.
#
# Created: Tue Jan 28 15:53:22 2020
#      by: pyside2-uic  running on PySide2 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MyWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, MyWidget):
        MyWidget.setObjectName("MyWidget")
        MyWidget.resize(220, 254)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(MyWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MyWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MyWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(MyWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, MyWidget):
        MyWidget.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MyWidget", "Form", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MyWidget", "picture", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MyWidget", "PushButton", None, -1))
```

And Mainwindow.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MainWindow.ui',
# licensing of 'MainWindow.ui' applies.
#
# Created: Tue Jan 28 15:53:39 2020
#      by: pyside2-uic  running on PySide2 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.widget = MyWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(170, 85, 255, 100);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget_2 = MyWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(170, 85, 255, 100);")
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget_4 = MyWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(170, 85, 255, 100);")
        self.widget_4.setObjectName("widget_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget_3 = MyWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(170, 85, 255, 100);")
        self.widget_3.setObjectName("widget_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, -1))

from mywidget import MyWidget
```

Any Idea on what is wrong ? did I made a mistake when I've done my "promote to" process ?

Thx for your help!

Comment: when I check the file generated, I see that the MyWidget class is not "MyWidget anymore but "Ui_MyWidget". I replaced the new name in the import line, but the cmd windows close immediately. is it a good thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code generated by pyside2-uic is not a class of a widget but a class that is used to fill in a widget, that is easily observed since Ui_MyWidget and Ui_MainWindow do not inherit from a widget but only from object.

The solution is to create the class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the previous class to fill it. The following steps must be performed:

1. Convert the .ui to .py using pyside2-uic, to differentiate them, place the prefix ui_, also do not use ">" since it can generate errors caused by the coding of the console.

   ```
   pyside2-uic MyWidget.ui -o ui_mywidget.py -x
   pyside2-uic MainWindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py -x
   ```
2. Create the classes that implement the widgets where the previous classes will be used:

   **mywidget.py**

   ```py
   from PySide2 import QtWidgets

   from ui_mywidget import Ui_MyWidget


   class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_MyWidget):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super().__init__(parent)
           self.setupUi(self)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import sys

       app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
       w = MyWidget()
       w.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

   **mainwindow.py**

   ```py
   from PySide2 import QtWidgets

   from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow


   class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super().__init__(parent)
           self.setupUi(self)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import sys

       app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
       w = MainWindow()
       w.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

With the above you must have the following files:

```
├── mainwindow.py
├── MainWindow.ui
├── mywidget.py
├── MyWidget.ui
├── ui_mainwindow.py
└── ui_mywidget.py
```

Comment: In addition to this, to reduce the number of steps and files you can also import .ui files directly without converting them to .py files first. See for example [the official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html).

Comment: If I whant to distribute the software using pyinstaller for example. Is it better to use .ui or .py files?

Comment: Don't worry, it was late for me yesterday. I'll try it today, and not forgot to check!